# ExecutorService restart

Tags: java, android, executorservice

Can I restart an `ExecutorService` to start accepting new task after it has been shutdown?

Or I have to always create new `ExecutorService` instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), there is no method to restart an `ExecutorService`, as it is an interface without such a method you can infer that there is no way to restart it. That said, as `ExecutorService` is an interface, you could conceivably write an implementation that does restart (but you would have to reference it by its concrete type or another interface). I wouldn't recommend it though. Just use the existing ones and recreate them as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any indication that you can do that from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

What is the problem with creating new ones?

Comment: Just wondering If I could. I Thought of implementing a class that have an instance of the ExecutorService. Part of that class has methods Start(), Stop(). So In my start, I was wondering if doing myExecutor.ScheduleAtFixedRate would restart the executor even after doing a myExecutor.shutdown() in my Stop() method. Instead of creating a new Executor each time in the Start().